# How to block WordPress from resizing GIFs?

Tags: wordpress, gif, image-resizing

The GIF images in my WordPress blog posts look very bad, especially on mobile.

[image]

I see that they are resized because their URL looks like that:

```
https://i2.wp.com/blog.com/wp-content/.../image.gif?zoom=2.625&resize=300%2C180&ssl=1
```

instead of:

```
https://i2.wp.com/blog.com/wp-content/.../image.gif
```

It's strange that the resizing is made while the page is rendered. I mean the GIF looks good in the very first second you see it, but after that, it gets resized.

Do you know how can I block WordPress from resizing the GIF images only? Thank you!

Comment: probably a theme you are using and/or a plugin. anyhow you should attach some code from source if you want help on that and not from the result only.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, I'm using Divi 3.0 theme. What kind of source code do you mean..?